# Align one item to left of ActionBar

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, menuitem

I want to align one item to the left of ActionBar and others to the right like this :

[image]

I have 5 items in my menu xml.

**main.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="fr.mgs.consulting.allbrary_android.MainActivity" >

<item 
    android:id="@+id/action_spinner"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/spinner_actionbar"
    android:title="@string/action_spinner"

    android:orderInCategory="1"/>

<item 
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/action_spinner"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:orderInCategory="2"/>

<item 
    android:id="@+id/action_tablet"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_spinner"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_tablet"
    android:orderInCategory="3"/>

<item 
    android:id="@+id/action_notifications"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/action_spinner"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_notifications"
    android:orderInCategory="4"/>

<item 
    android:id="@+id/action_user"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/action_spinner"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_user"
    android:orderInCategory="5"/>
```

How shall we do it?
Sorry for my very bad English.

Answer (score -1):

You can create your own custom view for ActionBar where this left element will be like simple image view, and others menu items will be as usual menu items.

Example here: http://javatechig.com/android/actionbar-with-custom-view-example-in-android

Comment: Yes but I want to keep the icon android.R.id.home for the Navigation Drawer